# Scroll a GridView inside a SemanticZoom to a certain group from outside the SemanticZoom

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, semantic-zoom

I'm trying to add a custom alphabetical selection outside the `SemanticZoom` in addition to alphabetical selection in the `ZoomedOutView`, but I can't manage to manipulate the `GridView` in the `ZoomedInView`

[image: <code>ZoomedOutView</code> with the alphabetical selection in the top right]

[image: <code>ZoomedInView</code> with the alphabetical selection in the top right]

As of now the `ItemSource` of the two alphabetical views are the same and are set in the code-behind.

The `SemanticZoom` works fine, but what I'm trying to achieve is when one of the letters in the top right is clicked, it scrolls to the corresponding group in the `ZoomedInView`.

Is there any way of achieving this?

(I didn't include any code as the code itself isn't the main issue here, but please let me know if it ought to be included)

Comment: Does the item source contain only the data for D and E alphabets or does it populate all ?

Comment: @Anobik it contains all the data. As of now I update the item source to just display the corresponding letter when it is tapped, but that requires a reset button to show all the items again once one is tapped, which is not desirable. That solution also messes up the zoomedOutView.

Comment: So basically You need two things 
1 - Create a scrolling effect
2 - update the itemsource with corrosponding alphabets clicked?

in the zoomed in view ? Am i right? Then ill proceed with some workarounds as an answer.

Comment: @Anobik Yeah, that sounds about right! :) Thank you!

Comment: Please check the solution. Type of a Demo but will make your concept clear :)

Comment: @Anobik Thank you so much for your reply! I've checked the solution and I understand the workaround, and I'll try to implement it in my solution. I'll get back to you as soon as I'm done :)

Comment: @Anobik Thanks again for your reply! I've accepted the answer as it partly solved my issue. It gave me a way of scrolling the GridView from outside the SemanticZoom, but I couldn't figure out how to scroll to the different groups inside the scrollview. Maybe we misunderstood eachother, but I already have all the items I want in the view, the issue arose when I wanted to navigate to a certain group. I figured out a way to get the position of the different items and scroll to that offset, but it turned out that some of the items was null if they were located far away from the displaying ones.

Comment: Ok one more thing I experienced this in winJS .. A list view loads only some specific amount of items .. Maybe 16 or 17 .... And does a lazy loading kind of stuff :) I dont know in c# never faced that . It might be the reason. You can go ahead and explore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I came up with a work around. I am giving the Code but before that download the Gridview sample from msdn link.

[GridView Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-ListView-and-GridView-8a5ff99f)

And changes to see the effect is to be done in **ScenarioOutput1.xaml** and **ScenarioOutput1.xaml.cs**.

So Lets Start with ScenarioOutput1.xaml Codethat I changed Please copy paste it into the project (GridView Demo from msdn) to see the effect if you have difficulty understanding the code.

ScenarioOutput1.xaml

```
    <Page
    x:Class="ListViewSimple.ScenarioOutput1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" Width="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <GridView x:Name="ItemGridView" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StoreFrontTileTemplate}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StoreFrontTileStyle}"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource StoreFrontGridItemsPanelTemplate}"
            BorderBrush="LightGray"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            BorderThickness="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            SelectionMode="None"/>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Now the next part the cs file.

ScenarioOutput1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using SDKTemplateCS;
using Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource;

namespace ListViewSimple
{
    public sealed partial class ScenarioOutput1 : Page
    {
        // A pointer back to the main page which is used to gain access to the input and output frames and their content.
        MainPage rootPage = null;
        StoreData storeData = null;
        private Item item;
        private Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource.ItemCollection _collectionNew = new Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource.ItemCollection();
        public ScenarioOutput1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            storeData = new StoreData();
            ItemGridView.ItemsSource = storeData.Collection;
        }

        #region Template-Related Code - Do not remove
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get a pointer to our main page.
            rootPage = e.Parameter as MainPage;

            // We want to be notified with the OutputFrame is loaded so we can get to the content.
            rootPage.InputFrameLoaded += new System.EventHandler(rootPage_InputFrameLoaded);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            rootPage.InputFrameLoaded -= new System.EventHandler(rootPage_InputFrameLoaded);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Use this code if you need access to elements in the input frame - otherwise delete
        void rootPage_InputFrameLoaded(object sender, object e)
        {
            // At this point, we know that the Input Frame has been loaded and we can go ahead
            // and reference elements in the page contained in the Input Frame.

            // Get a pointer to the content within the IntputFrame.
            Page inputFrame = (Page)rootPage.InputFrame.Content;

            // Go find the elements that we need for this scenario
            // ex: flipView1 = inputFrame.FindName("FlipView1") as FlipView;
        }
        #endregion

        Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");
        private DispatcherTimer _timer;
        private async void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                item = new Item();
                item.Title = "This is a new One First";
                item.SetImage(_baseUri, "SampleData/Images/60SprinklesRainbow.png");
                item.Subtitle = "Ultrices rutrum sapien vehicula semper lorem volutpat sociis sit maecenas praesent taciti magna nunc odio orci vel tellus nam sed accumsan iaculis dis est";
                item.Link = "http://www.blueyonderairlines.com/";
                item.Category = "Ice Cream";
                item.Description = "Consectetuer lacinia vestibulum tristique sit adipiscing laoreet fusce nibh suspendisse natoque placerat pulvinar ultricies condimentum scelerisque nisi ullamcorper nisl parturient vel suspendisse nam venenatis nunc lorem sed dis sagittis pellentesque luctus sollicitudin morbi posuere vestibulum potenti magnis pellentesque vulputate mattis mauris mollis consectetuer pellentesque pretium montes vestibulum condimentum nulla adipiscing sollicitudin scelerisque ullamcorper pellentesque odio orci rhoncus pede sodales suspendisse parturient viverra curabitur proin aliquam integer augue quam condimentum quisque senectus quis urna scelerisque nostra phasellus ullamcorper cras duis suspendisse sociosqu dolor vestibulum condimentum consectetuer vivamus est fames felis suscipit hac";
                item.Content = "aaaA";

                _collectionNew.Add(item);

                item = new Item();
                item.Title = "This is a new One Second";
                item.Subtitle = "Ultrices rutrum sapien vehicula semper lorem volutpat sociis sit maecenas praesent taciti magna nunc odio orci vel tellus nam sed accumsan iaculis dis est";
                item.Link = "http://www.blueyonderairlines.com/";
                item.Category = "Ice Cream";
                item.SetImage(_baseUri, "SampleData/Images/60SprinklesRainbow.png");
                item.Description = "Consectetuer lacinia vestibulum tristique sit adipiscing laoreet fusce nibh suspendisse natoque placerat pulvinar ultricies condimentum scelerisque nisi ullamcorper nisl parturient vel suspendisse nam venenatis nunc lorem sed dis sagittis pellentesque luctus sollicitudin morbi posuere vestibulum potenti magnis pellentesque vulputate mattis mauris mollis consectetuer pellentesque pretium montes vestibulum condimentum nulla adipiscing sollicitudin scelerisque ullamcorper pellentesque odio orci rhoncus pede sodales suspendisse parturient viverra curabitur proin aliquam integer augue quam condimentum quisque senectus quis urna scelerisque nostra phasellus ullamcorper cras duis suspendisse sociosqu dolor vestibulum condimentum consectetuer vivamus est fames felis suscipit hac";
                item.Content = "aaaa";

                _collectionNew.Add(item);
                scroller.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(2000);
                _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(3000);
                _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
                _timer.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            ItemGridView.ItemsSource = null;
            ItemGridView.ItemsSource = _collectionNew;
                 _timer.Stop();
        }
    }


}
```

Please implement it in the demo and see the effect. there might be other work arounds but wanted to clear the stuff as easy and soon as possible. Let me know if you have any trouble understanding :)